# Oracle APEX - accessing fields from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there a way to access fields on APEX page that are not page items and therefore cannot be accessed with `:P2_ITEM`?

`v$` does not work either. All I have is the field ID which can be accessed with javascript but I need to access from PL/SQL or somehow pass it to PL/SQL

Comment: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2014/02/dont-always-call-v/

Comment: Why are you in such a position? This page would complain upon submission. You can still pass through to PL/SQL as x01 parameter in manual apex.server.process call, using $('#ITEM').val()

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create corresponding APEX page item and then fill it's value using JavaScript.

For example:

```
var fieldValue = //the way you said you can access it

$s('P2_CREATED_ITEM', fieldValue);
```

After that you can reference the value in PL/SQL code via `P2_CREATED_ITEM` APEX item.

Answer (score 0):

> give id to that field 
>   create a page item .like P2_ITEM.
>   create a dynamic action on page load .select action is javascript.which load data from field to item.

```
 var box1 = $('#FIELD_ID');
        var box2 = $('#P2_ITEM');
        box2.val(box1.val());
```

> then u can access whatever in the field.